# Display text in input from the end

Tags: html, css

I want use CSS to display a content in input from the end of this content. That mean, if the content length is over input length, then we always see the last character (look like when you focus on input and set the cursor at the end of line). This is very similar with:

```
text-align:right;
```

But I don't want use text-align: right, because the text always aligns from right. I want it aligns from left as normally, just display from the end of content.
[image]

Comment: it's not possible with pure CSS. You can achieve this using javascript.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour of input(text) tag?

Comment: why not using js? You probably have used js to set the value of it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I used another way, just use textarea, not input. It's simpler :)